# Rails create record with status published if all parameters are set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Event model has following fields:

```
  create_table "group_events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "start_date", null: false
    t.date "end_date
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "status", default: "draft"
```

I've got a requirement that the event should be draft or published. To publish all of the fields are required, it can be saved with only a subset of fields before it’s published. How to recognize if a record should be saved as a draft or published?

```
  def create_event
    Event.create!(
      start_date: params[:start_date],
      end_date: params[:end_date],
      name: params[:name],
      description: params[:description],
      user_id: params[:user_id]
    )
  end
```

Should I count params and based on that set status in `create_event` method or is there any better way to do so?

Comment: Should the event status be automatically set to `published` if all the attributes are present or should the user decide when to publish the event??

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan All requirements are in the post, I don't know anything else. Probably it should be automatically set to published.

Answer (score 2):

You could register a `before_save` [ActiveRecord callback](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to set the status to `published` if the event is publishable.

```rb
# app/models/event.rb

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_status

  private

  def set_status
    self.status = 'published' if publishable?
  end

  def publishable?
    [
      name,
      description,
      end_date
    ].all?(&:present?) # Add other fields as required. `start_date` is omitted since it's required.
  end
end
```